# Using SecondaryBTreeDatabase with DuplicatesPolicy.SORTED on primary BTreeDatabase

Tags: c#, .net, berkeley-db

I have a problem with Berkeley DB for .NET 3.5 (version 5.0.21 to be exact).

Here's my setup that worked just fine when it used `primaryKeyDuplicatesPolicy = DuplicatesPolicy.NONE` on primary DB:

```cs
var btcfg = new BTreeDatabaseConfig
                {
                        Duplicates = primaryKeyDuplicatesPolicy,
                        Creation = CreatePolicy.IF_NEEDED,
                        FreeThreaded = false,
                        ErrorPrefix = "bdbIndex",
                        ReadUncommitted = false,
                        UseMVCC = false,
                        CacheSize = new CacheInfo(cacheSize, 0, 1),
                };
var primaryDb = BTreeDatabase.Open(additionalPath + "primary.db", btcfg);
var secondaryDb = SecondaryBTreeDatabase.Open(additionalPath + "secondary.db",
                  new SecondaryBTreeDatabaseConfig(PrimaryDb, GetSecondaryDbKey)
                      {
                          AutoCommit = btcfg.AutoCommit,
                          Creation = CreatePolicy.IF_NEEDED,
                          FreeThreaded = btcfg.FreeThreaded,
                          ErrorPrefix = btcfg.ErrorPrefix,
                          ReadUncommitted = btcfg.ReadUncommitted,
                          UseMVCC = btcfg.UseMVCC,
                          Env = env,
                          Duplicates = DuplicatesPolicy.NONE
                      });
```

Now, as soon as I change `primaryKeyDuplicatesPolicy` to any other value, everything breaks on `SecondaryBTreeDatabase.Open()` with exception `BerkeleyDB.DatabaseException : Invalid argument`.

So, is it possible to have secondary DB with duplicates in primary DB? (Manual says that yes, it is possible, as far as I understand).

Second, what am I doing wrong and what should I do to make this thing work?

PS: I've tried initializing Environment, but that doesn't help. Also, splitting the logic into two primary DBs would be painful at the moment.